# Count duplicates in a row using only one cell formula (no conditional formatting either)

Tags: excel, duplicates, countif

I have a row of data, let's say (a, b, c, d, e, a, c)
I want to count the number of duplicates - in this case, 2 (2 a's, 2 c's)
However, I do not want to use COUNTIF(RNG,A1)>1 and drag out for the entire length of the list.
I would like to search the row for all values in the range and count if it finds a match.

Comment: If the dragging is a drag on you use `Find & Select > GoTo` instead.

Comment: totally a drag, but hoping for one formula to do the trick.

Comment: Are you using Excel 365 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the frequency version (for earlier versions of Excel) for completeness:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A1:H1,A1:H1,0),MATCH(A1:H1,A1:H1,0))>1))
```

counts the number of different letters with frequency>1 which is (a,c) =>2

There is also an alternative interpretation of the question, which is 'how many duplicates exist in total?' (i.e. one for a, two for c making three altogether):

```
=COUNTA(A1:H1)-SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A1:H1,A1:H1,0),MATCH(A1:H1,A1:H1,0))>0))
```

Counts the total number of letters (8) minus the number of unique letters (5) (a,c,c) => 3

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have Excel 365, then:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((1/COUNTIF(A1:G1,A1:G1)<1)*(1/COUNTIF(A1:G1,A1:G1)))
```

[image]

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif 'This is a cool and elegant formula, but it calculates much more slowly than formulas that use FREQUENCY to count unique values' ( know you're counting duplicates here, but same thing applies)

Comment: @TomSharpe - good to know... I didn't even see that on exceljet, just pulled that formula from memory.

Answer (score 1):

With Excel 365 and data in **A1** thru **G1**, pick a cell and enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(A1:G1,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(A1:G1)))>1))
```

[image]

*(this is actually the method indicated in your question, but with all the helper arrays hidden)*

**NOTES:**

this:

```
UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(A1:G1))
```

will produce an array like:
a
b
c
d
e
and this:

```
COUNTIF(A1:G1,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(A1:G1)))
```

will produce:
2
1
2
1
1
and the `SUMPRODUCT()` counts how many of the above are greater  one.